# Change the color of button in particular tr of html table after submitting the form

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp

Following code consists of html part. 
       I need to change the color of button of a particular row on click of it after all values in table body are validated

```
   This code changes the color of button on click of it before validation.

<tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="val in finalData[0]" ">
                    <td><button type="button"
                    ng-click="storeTicketKey(val.TicketKey,val.clicked = !val.clicked)" class="btn btn-primary" 
                    ng-class="{'btn-danger': !val.clicked, 'btn-success': val.clicked }"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{val.TicketKey}}</button></td>
                    <td>{{val.Status}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.AssignedGroup}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.AssignedTo}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L1}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L2}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L3}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L4}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L5}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.AssignedTo}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.ResponseSLAStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.ResolutionSLAStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.Region}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.SLABreachReason}}</td>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Is this for AngularJS 1.x?

Comment: yes,I have used this version

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you provided a solution would be removing the ng-class attribute and instead creating a (click)= "checkFields(event)" on the button and in your .ts you can create the function which will check the validity of the fields and change the class of your component.

Your .html:

```
<td><button type="button" ng-click="storeTicketKey(val.TicketKey,val.clicked = !val.clicked)" class="btn btn-primary" "checkFields(event)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{val.TicketKey}}</button></td>
```

Your .ts:

```
checkFields(event: any){
    //Check if the fields are valid, in this case I only check if they exist
    if(!val.Status){
        return;
    }if(!val.AssignedGroup){
        return; 
    }
    .. and so on for all the fields you want to test

    //If all variables are valid and the function gets to the end
    //You change the class of the button
    event.target.className = 'btn-success';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have solved the problem by another way using 'track by $index'. $index retains the index of every button which you can use for changing the color of a particular button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="val in finalData[0] track by $index ">
                    <td><button type="button"
                    ng-click="storeTicketKey(val.TicketKey, $index)" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-class="{'btn-success':  $index=== isActive}"                   
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{val.TicketKey}}</button></td>
                    <td>{{val.Status}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.AssignedGroup}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.AssignedTo}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L1}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L2}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L3}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L4}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.L5}}</td>                 
                    <td>{{val.ResponseSLAStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.ResolutionSLAStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.Region}}</td>
                    <td>{{val.SLABreachReason}}</td>
            </tbody>


$scope.valClicked=false;
    $scope.isActive = "";
    $scope.tempTicket="";
    $scope.storeTicketKey = function(ticketKey,str) {
        $scope.finalTicketKey=ticketKey;
        $scope.tempTicket = str;
//      $scope.valClicked=val;

    }

    $scope.isActiveButton = function(){

        $scope.isActive = $scope.tempTicket;

    }
```